# Spring boot with external jar 'Not a Managed Type'

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

I have a spring application that is pulling in a commons jar. This jar has DTO classes with annotations. Running the mvn clean build command runs successfully and builds the jar.  Once i run java -jar target/MyApp-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar i will get the below error.

I have opend the MyApp-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar and found all my classes inside that jar.

I have opened the jar that contains MyApplicationJobDTO inside my snapshot and verified the file is there.

It seems that at runtime java cannot find the class even though the class is there. I dont believe i should have to add anything to java class path since the jar is located inside of the snapshot jar. I am stuck and unsure of why i am getting runtime errors.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com...MyApplicationJobDTO
```

Class with its annotations

```
@Component
@Entity
public class MyApplicationJobDTO implements Serializable {
```

My command to run

```
mvn clean package && java -jar target/MyApp-1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

My Main class

```
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ApplicationContext context = 
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file:src/main/java/com/myapp/beans.xml");

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

</beans>
```

Error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyApplicationJobController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.myapp.xx.yy.models.MyApplicationJobDAO com.myapp.xx.yy.web.MyApplicationJobController.MyApplicationJobDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyApplicationJobDAO': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.myapp.aa.bb.myapptest.commons.dto.MyApplicationJobDTO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:109)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:691)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:952)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:941)
    at com.myapp.xx.yy.Application.main(Application.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.myapp.xx.yy.models.MyApplicationJobDAO com.myapp.xx.yy.web.MyApplicationJobController.MyApplicationJobDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyApplicationJobDAO': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.myapp.aa.bb.myapptest.commons.dto.MyApplicationJobDTO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:290)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'MyApplicationJobDAO': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.myapp.aa.bb.myapptest.commons.dto.MyApplicationJobDTO
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1554)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:964)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:862)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:481)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class com.myapp.aa.bb.myapptest.commons.dto.MyApplicationJobDTO
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:219)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getMetadata(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:65)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:149)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:158)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:92)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1613)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1550)
```

**edit** If i manually add all the classes in my external jar that need to be used in my spring project it works. I still cannot get the classes to load from an external jar

Answer (score 5):

I gave the same answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41145229/372838 but this question states more clearly the problem only occurs when running the spring boot application as a JAR

---

In my project we experienced a similar problem. When running with `mvn spring-boot:start` the `@EntityScan` works fine and can find all entities including those in libraries. When we run the springboot application using `java -jar` the application cannot find entities that are referenced via a maven dependency. It seems the classloading is different when the springboot application is run as a jar.

You can instruct spring-boot to 'unpack' the JAR dependency that contains the entities that can not be found. You can add the following section to your `pom.xml`:

```
<project>
  ...

  <build>
      <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                  <requiresUnpack>
                      <dependency>
                          <groupId>org.example.pkg.commons</groupId>
                          <artifactId>domain-jar</artifactId>
                      </dependency>
                  </requiresUnpack>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 4):

Remove [@EntityScan](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/EntityScan.html) it is **Deprecated**. If you use the @EntityScan it will override @ComponentScan

or

you should specify the base package to scan for the JPA entities.
**@EntityScan("com.myapp.xx.yy.models")**

Comment: I tried removing `@EntityScan` and just using `@ComponentScan` but i still got the same error. I added `@EntityScan("com.myapp.xx.yy.models")` and removed `@ComponentScan` and got the same results but if i added `@EntityScan("my.external.jar.package.DTO")` it found the correct DTO but threw the same error but for a class in my local project. I tried adding  `@EntityScan( {"my.external.jar.package.DTO","my.local.project.package.DTO"})` but it seems @EntityScan will only scan 1 and not both.

Comment: if you removed the 'EntityScan' you have to still give the basePackage to in xxxx.yyyy.zzz  @ComponentScan

Comment: I added the following but still got the same error `@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.myapp.xx.yy.dto","com.myapp.xx.yy.myapp.commons.dto"})
@EntityScan({"com.myapp.xx.yy.dto","com.myapp.xx.yy.myapp.commons.dto"})`

Answer (score 3):

Your application package is probably different from that of your DTO class so Spring can't find it. You could do

```
@ComponentScan("com.myapp.xx.yy.models")
```

Comment: I have specifically added @ComponentScan("com.myapp.xx.yy.myproject.commons.dto.MyDTO") and @ComponentScan("com.myapp.xx.yy.myproject.commons.dto")  but i still get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type on running my jar

Comment: Put that in the component scan... Even better move your application class to a top level package so that every package is scanned. By default component scanning (and entityscannig) starts from the package in which the application class resided and its subpackages. It doesn't look up or packages outside of its scope.

Comment: @tiggles did you try adding all affected/dependent packages in the scan list in `@ComponentScan`?

Comment: I added `@ComponentScan("com.myapp.xx.yy.models")`, i tried  `@ComponentScan("com.externaljar.dto")`, i tried `@ComponentScan("com.externaljar.dto.ClassName")` and all give me the same exception of `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an managed type: class...` Also my Applicaiton.java which has my main class in it is at com.myproject.xx.yy and everything else is under com.myproject.xx.yy.something

Comment: @Reimeus all dependant classes for my dto that keeps failing are under the same package. So i assume if i added "com.externaljar.dto" it would pick up all my classes. I will specify them all and try.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is late, however, I had the same situation where my entities and repository are parked in the external jar file. After many tries, I found the solution by declaring `@SpringBootApplication` and `@ComponentScan` with the `basePackage` parameter.

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.external.yourExternalPackage.*" })
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.external.model.foo.entity" })
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I've to add \@EntityScan (basePackages = { "com.external.lib" }) \@EnableJpaRepositories (basePackages = { "com.external.lib" }) \@SpringBootApplication (basePackages = { "com.external.lib" })

to application class to make it works.
Is there a simple way ?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I sorted it out by adding this class:

```
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "com.internal.model", "com.external.model" })
@Configuration
public class ScanJPA {}
```

Make sure to include both the root packages of your JPA entities, that internal and that defined in the dependency, external jar.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to dvtoever, I also added my answer to the linked question but will add it here in case it helps someone who comes across this in the future.

---

My project had a similar problem with a Spring Boot application. I had the `@Entity` class in the common jar at a package such as `com.foo.jpa`, then an application jar that depended on the common jar. The application jar had the main `@SpringBootApplication` class at a package such as `com.foo.bar.appname`. `@EntityScan`, `@ComponentScan`, and `@EnableJpaRepositories` did not detect the `@Entity` class and gave the "Not a managed type" error regardless of what package names I provided to the annotations.

I finally fixed it by renaming the package names. I put the `@SpringBootApplicationapplication` class at `com.foo.bar` and the `@Entity` class in the common jar at `com.foo.bar.whatever`. As long as the `@Entity` class in the common jar was at the same package or a subpackage of the `@SpringBootApplication` class, it was autodetected, regardless of which jar it was in.