# Springboot @EntityScan not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Springboot application and my entity model is separated from my main application included as dependency.

my Application.java is located in this package com.a.b.c

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan("com.a.b")
public class Applciation
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         SpringApplication.run(Applciation.class, args);
    }
}
```

and my entity model is located in another project inside this package com.a.b

But I'm getting an error: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class

Comment: Check my answer on a similar post, hope it would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62480481/379173

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can relate to you. I have spent countless hours regarding this.

I'll divide your question to 3 parts (I will use "entity-project" and "spring-project" to refer to the project containing entity classes and main project trying to incorporate entity classes) :

Part 1 of 3: Making sure your entity classes are exposed in entity-project.

Create a Config at the root of entity-project

```
package com.a.b

@Configuration
@Import ({Entity1.class, Entity1Repo.class, Entity1Key.class, 
  Entity2.class, ... })
class EntityConfig {}
```

Part 2 of 3: Making sure your entity classes are in the classpath of spring-project.

Since you are using SpringBoot, I'm sure you are using maven (or Gradle).

Anyway, make sure you maven install the entity-project with entity classes:

```
cd /path/to/entity-project/
mvn install -DskipTests
```

In spring-project's maven file, include  to the entity-project.

Part 3 of 3: Use the EntityScan annotation.

It is just my taste, but I prefer using basePackageClasses instead of basePackage.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {Entity1.class}) 
// use basePackageClasses to avoid type errors
@Import({com.a.b.EntityConfig.class}) // this is what you are missing
public class Applciation
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         SpringApplication.run(Applciation.class, args);
    }
}
```

Viola!